# Showing warning when function result is not assigned to variable

Tags: c#, function

I have a function that returns a modified copy of the object that was passed to this function. I often do something like this:

```
obj = obj.Foo(param);
```

Don't ask why, I simply have to. But sometimes, I (and others) forgot to assign the return value, doing this:

```
obj.Foo(param);
```

which repeatedly leads to time-consuming debugging.

Is there any way to show a warning or error every time when the function result is not assigned to a variable? Or any other suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: "Don't ask why." Don't worry! The given code snippet is indicative of an immutable coding style (not saying that's what you're using). It's the same style you would use if, for example, you were modifying a `DateTime` variable. `date = date.AddDays(1);`

Comment: Solve the problem by not making the mistake in the first place. And we all do it, but that's really the only answer.

Comment: Apparently [ReSharper 6](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/) has a *"Return value of pure method is not used"* warning. (I'm only on v5 so can't test that this warning would apply in your situtation; I reckon that it probably would.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an out parameter, so the call would look like this:

```
obj.Foo(param, out obj);
```

Comment: This would break the possibility of writing statements like `obj = obj.Foo(param).Bar(parem).Baz(parum);`

Comment: I has taken this solution into account. I don't use chains like above, but I'm not sure I'll never use them. I was also looking for something more 'sophisticated' :D
You convinced me to this method :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Resharper to assist with this issue; you need to decorate your method with the `[Pure]` attribute:

```
[Pure]
public static IList<T> RemoveItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> thisList, T item)
{
    var list = thisList.ToList();
    list.Remove(item);
    return list;
}
```

then when you call it without assigning the return value you will see:

[image]

The `[Pure]` attribute is defined in Resharpers Data Annotations: You need to copy the classes into your project so you can reference them (many very useful other annotations too)

[image]

Comment: [JetBrains.Annotations.PureAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#PureAttribute) | [System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute)

Answer (score 2):

It's totally legal and often desirable to not assign the return parameter so it would be wrong to have a warning for it. [Henrik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148897/henrik) answer to use an `out` parameter is what I'd recommend too to ensure the result is assigned everytime.

Answer (score 2):

you can enable visual studio warings.

[image]

you can even customize the rule you want to apply.

you should see warnings in the case you don't assign the function to a variable

you can also decide to treat the waring as errors

Example:

```
  public static class MyClass
    {

      public static string GetStr()
       {
           return "";
       }
        public static void Main()
        {
            GetStr();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: for the older version you can use the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y20cc1z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Not available in all versions? I use VS 2008 Express which doesn't have "Code Analysis" tab. And I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: have a look at the link in the comment it shows how you can do that with the previous version

Comment: I have looked at the link, I choose version 2008, but the description is not relevant to my VS2008 Express. I can't see any Compile tab. I found "Treat All Warnings as Errors" in Debug tab, but I can't see Disable All Warnings check box anywhere. What's more, what is ID of this type of warning? How make this warning to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on answers, lacking stackoverflow credits. But I agree with Chris that it's totally legal and often desirable not to assign values returned from a method.  It's also occasionally not desirable.  e.g.

```
public static int Square(this int myValue)
{
    return myValue * myValue;
}
```

It's clear that calling this method without assigning it is probably a bug. I think creating a code analysis rule that warned every time you didn't assign a value as Massimiliano suggested would be worse than not having the rule at all.  In such cases it would be nice to be able to apply an attribute to the method...

```
[MustAssign]
public static int Square...
```

You could create a rule as Massimiliano suggested but only invoke the warning when the method is adorned with the attribute and the value returned from the method is not assigned.  Not a trivial exercise though.