# Can I make Visual Studio warn me when I forget to assign String.Replace()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I just wrote the following line of C# code, and then spent a couple of minutes troubleshooting when the program didn't work as expected:

```
myString.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
```

(`myString`, `oldValue`, and `newValue` are all string variables.)

Obviously my *intent* was to cause the `myString` variable to be reassigned a new string equal to the original `myString` value but with the `oldValue` substring replaced by `newValue`.

Equally obviously (in hindsight), that line of code didn't work because I should have assigned the return value of `Replace()` back to `myString:`

```
myString = myString.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
```

Even though I'm well aware that C# strings are immutable and therefore methods like `Replace()` are written to return a new string instance, I still find myself accidentally writing bad code like the original line of code above on occasion.

My question is: Can I get Visual Studio to give me a compile-time warning in this situation, to save me from needing to manually find and diagnose the problem at runtime?

Note that since I'm using a .Net framework method here (String.Replace), rewriting the method in question to use an `out` parameter (as in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6913144/12484)) isn't really an option.

Comment: Don't agree it's a duplicate. All the answers focus on writing your code so that your code won't have these issues. This is about catching issues from system libraries. FxCop or Resharper can actually flag these quite elegantly.

Comment: There ought to be an alarm going off between your ears.  A method that clearly *alters* something but is not called with a *ref* or *out* argument.  Cheapest tool you can find.  You also make this mistake only once, everybody remembers it.

Comment: @HansPassant - Absolutely, I agree, there *ought* to be! For some reason, though, this is a bit of a blind spot for me personally -- I only posted this question after about the third time I had this happen (over a period of a few months). Also, a counterargument: some methods (albeit on non-primitive types) do alter their arguments without a ref or out (and return void), such as the Array.Reverse method.

Comment: Actually, I guess a better example would be a method that alters the object that the method is being called on, like the List<T>.Add method.

Comment: @HansPassant "You also make this mistake only once, everybody remembers it." Speak for yourself, I've been making this mistake consistently for a decade. A compiler warning would really be nice, without the incredible performance burden of Resharper.

Comment: Hmya, that happens when you leave it up to a crutch to set the alarm off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ReSharper, it will give you a warning indicating that you are ignoring the return value from a method, when you don't assign the return value to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! As I mentioned in the question, though, I'm hoping that there's a gratis solution available.

Answer (score 1):

I [have created a custom FxCop rule that handles this case for ignoring](http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/FxCopContrib/DoNotIgnoreResultOfImmutableMethods.cs) the result from a call to an immutable type method.

the basic gist is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// We need to find all Pop nodes, these are a member of the ExpressionStatement class.
/// After we find a Pop statement (which ignores the current value on the stack), we will see if the value added
/// to the stack is an instance MethodCall on an ImmutableType.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="statement"></param>
public override void VisitExpressionStatement(ExpressionStatement statement)
{
    if (statement == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("statement"); }

    if (statement.Expression.NodeType == NodeType.Pop)
    {
        VisitUnaryExpression(statement.Expression as UnaryExpression);
    }
    base.VisitExpressionStatement(statement);
}

/// <summary>
/// When we've found the UnaryExpression we check it for a MethodCall on an ImmutableType
/// </summary>
/// <param name="unaryExpression"></param>
public override void VisitUnaryExpression(UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
{
    if (unaryExpression == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("unaryExpression"); }

    if (unaryExpression.NodeType == NodeType.Pop)
    {
        MethodCall call = unaryExpression.Operand as MethodCall;
        if (call != null)
        {
            MemberBinding binding = call.Callee as MemberBinding;
            if (binding.BoundMember.DeclaringType != null
                && immutableTypes.Contains(binding.BoundMember.DeclaringType.FullName))
            {
                Method method = binding.BoundMember as Method;

                // If the method also returns an immutable Type we flag it as a problem.
                if (immutableTypes.Contains(method.ReturnType.FullName))
                {
                    this.Problems.Add(new Problem(GetResolution(), call));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```